# How to estimate the rank of a huge, sparse csr_matrix using Python (and probably Scipy)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, rank

I have a huge, sparse matrix in the type of `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` that I need to estimate its rank. I find [this on scipy.org](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.interpolative.estimate_rank.html) that seems perfect for this job, but it doesn't support `csr_matrix`.

```
from scipy.sparse import load_npz
from scipy.linalg.interpolative import estimate_rank

X = load_npz("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1SSR6JWEqG4DXRU9qo78682D9pGJF3Wr0")
print("Rank:", estimate_rank(X, eps=100))
```

**TypeError: invalid input type (must be array or LinearOperator)**

The sparse matrix has over 50K rows and nearly 40K columns. Converting it to a numpy array first seems pointless. What should I do to make it work?

---

The following doesn't work either.

```
from scipy.sparse import load_npz, linalg
from scipy.linalg.interpolative import estimate_rank

X = load_npz("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1SSR6JWEqG4DXRU9qo78682D9pGJF3Wr0")
print("Rank:", estimate_rank(linag.aslinearoperator(X), eps=100))
```

[image]
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      3 
      4 print(type(X))
----> 5 print("Rank of the Document-Term Matrix:", estimate_rank(aslinearoperator(X), eps=1))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_interpolative_backend.py in idd_findrank(eps, m, n, matvect)
    659     :rtype: int
    660     """
--> 661     k, ra, ier = _id.idd_findrank(eps, m, n, matvect)
    662     if ier:
    663         raise _RETCODE_ERROR

ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (-1216667648,)

Comment: `doesn't work` is a useless description.

Answer (score 1):

I have used sparse, but haven't used `estimate_rank`.  But I can read errors and docs.

```
In [23]: from scipy import sparse                                                                      
In [24]: from scipy.sparse import linalg                                                               
In [25]: M = sparse.random(100,100,.2, 'csr')   

In [36]: inter.estimate_rank(M,.001)                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
TypeError: invalid input type (must be array or LinearOperator)
```

testing the array option:

```
In [37]: inter.estimate_rank(M.A,.1)                                                                   
Out[37]: 100
```

testing the linearoperator option:

```
In [38]: from scipy.sparse import linalg                                                               
In [39]: L = linalg.aslinearoperator(M)                                                                
In [40]: L                                                                                             
Out[40]: <100x100 MatrixLinearOperator with dtype=float64>
In [41]: inter.estimate_rank(L,.001)                                                                   
Out[41]: 99
```

Comment: Well, `estimate_rank(aslinearoperator(X), eps=100)` doesn't work either.

Comment: In my example I  reduce `eps`